# How to Assert file existing in other module - JUNIT

Tags: java, maven, junit, junit4

I have my directory structure like below

```
Root
|--A
   |--src
   |--target
   |--output.xml 

|--B
   |--src
       |--test
            |--java
                 |--MyTest.java
```

My Junit Test method looks like below`

```
@Test
public void testXmlGeneration() {
   File file = new File("output.xml");
    assertTrue(file.exists());
}
```

I want to check whether output.xml is generate in directory A or not. Above test is failing with

```
java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:86)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)
```

I tried with below approach as well, but its failing with NullPointerException.`

```
    File file = new File(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("A/output.xml").toString());
assertTrue(file.exists());
```

NullPointerException stack trace is as below

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.B.StatisticsTest.testXmlGeneration(StatisticsTest.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Comment: Try specifying the complete path as `new File("Root/A/output.xml")` and do share the NPR stacktrace.

Comment: Its failing with java.lang.AssertionError. StackTrace is same as above. @nullpointer

Answer (score 0):

```
   File file = new File(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("A/output.xml").toString());
```

its .toString() method. it won't consider as file that's why your getting that error you can  can try like below

```
  @Test
  public void test() {
    File f = new File(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("A/output.xml").getFile());      
    assertTrue(f.exists());
  }
```

Comment: failing with NullPointer Exception with same stacktrace above.

Comment: (this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("A/output.xml").getFile()) will return a file incase there is no such a file it will return nullpointer

Comment: Although file  is present, I suspect there maybe some configuration issue ! Anyway appreciate your quick response !